# How to create a Validation rule that makes field3 not equal to field2 in a table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm using MS-Access 2016. I had created a table1 with few fields. Then I created Table2. where my Field2 of table2 is having the source from Field3 of table1. then in field3 of a table2, I want to have validation rule where the Field3 of table2 should no be equal to Field 2 of table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to have validation rule where the Field3 of table2 should no be
>   equal to Field 2 of table2.

You can use a table-level *Validation Rule* for that.

1. Open `table2` in *Design View*.
2. Right-click the table's title area and open its property sheet.
3. Add `[Field3]<>[Field2]` in the box next to *Validation Rule*.
4. Save the table design, switch to *Datasheet View*, and edit values to confirm the validation is enforced as you intend.

The situation may be more complicated if your table design permits Nulls for both those fields.
 The *Validation Rule* above will accept a row with Null in both those fields.  But, if you want the fields to be considered equal (and therefore invalid) when both contain Null, use this instead:

```
[Field3]<>[Field2] And Not ([Field2] Is Null And [Field3] Is Null)
```